# Ramification of a prime in a number field

Tags: nt.number-theory

Consider the following number field $K = \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^{(p^2-1)/2}-p)}$ where $p$ is a prime. What is the factorization of the prime ideal $p$ in the ring of integers of $K$?

Comment: How about $(\alpha)^{(p^2-1)/2}$, where $\alpha$ is the root of the polynomial you adjoined?

Comment: How would I prove this? I also suspect that there is total ramification over $p$ but unable to prove this.

Comment: Well, from the defining equation for your number field we have the equation $\alpha^{(p^2-1)/2}=p$, hence the ideal $(p)$ equals $(\alpha)^{(p^2-1)/2}$. Now certainly the ideal $(\alpha)$ is prime in the ring of integers of $K$, since its ideal norm is the rational prime $p$ (since the norm of $\alpha$ is $-p$; we need to assume $p$ odd of course). So this means that $p=(\alpha)^{(p^2-1)/2}$ is the prime factorization of the ideal $p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested only in the ramification above a single prime number $p$, it is best to forget the field $\mathbf{Q}$ and work instead over the field $\mathbf{Q}_p$.  For every $n>0$, the polynomial $f=x^n-p$ is an Eisenstein polynomial over $\mathbf{Q}_p$, so it is irreducible,  and adjoining a root of $f$ gives a totally ramified extension of degree $n$.